# I can't get the circle onclick to make a line visibile

Tags: html, function, svg, onclick

Thank you, All in advance for any help you can offer to me.  I originally started this project in canvas and I'm now using SVG.

I'm trying to make the invisible line visible after I click on both dots.
As you can probably guess I'm new at this any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> BlackMoon_5</title>

<style> 
    body {background-color: #00FFFF}
    line {stroke: blue;visibility: hidden;}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<svg width="1000" height= "1000"> <!--does svg need and end tag?-->

<circle id="circle0"cx="50" cy="50" r="5" onClick="dotClick(0)">
</circle> <!-- Upper Dot code From html5.dk-->

<line id="line0"x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="100"> </line>

<circle id="circle1"cx="50" cy="100" r="5" onClick="dotClick(1)"> </circle> <!-- Lower dot -->

</svg>
</body>

<script>
function onClick() {
    document.getElementById("line0").style.visibility="visibile";

}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `onClick` JavaScript function be called `dotClick`? That's how you are referring to it in the SVG circle element.

Comment: To answer the question in the code, yes `<svg>` does need an end tag. You have to write SVG as xml and not as SGML.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your js. In the first place, you should call `dotClick` your event handler and not `onClick`. Also, you have to figure out a way to show the line when both circles have been clicked. I've used an object. I'm also changing the color of the clicked circle (just for testing purposes, you can get rid of it if you like). To make it visible, you can use the setAttribute of stroke:

```
var buttons = {};

function dotClick(width) {

    (width === 0) ? buttons.one = !buttons.one : buttons.two = !buttons.two;

    document.getElementById("line0").setAttribute("stroke", (buttons.one && buttons.two) ? "red" : "");
    document.getElementById("circle0").setAttribute("fill", (buttons.one ? "red" : "black"));    
    document.getElementById("circle1").setAttribute("fill", (buttons.two ? "red" : "black"));
}
```

You can check it in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4sr1sh7h/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You had a bunch of typos, and some missing logic.

```
    <doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title> BlackMoon_5</title>

        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #00FFFF;
            }

            line {
                stroke: blue;
                visibility: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="1000" height="1000">
            <!--does svg need and end tag?-->
            <circle id="circle0" cx="50" cy="50" r="5" onclick="dotClick(1);">
            </circle> <!-- Upper Dot code From html5.dk-->
            <line id="line0" x1="50" y1="50" x2="50" y2="100"> </line>
            <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="100" r="5" onclick="dotClick(2)"> </circle> <!-- Lower dot -->
        </svg>
    </body>

    <script>
    var clicked_1 = false;
    var clicked_2 = false;

    function dotClick(dot) {

        if(dot === 1){
            clicked_1 = true;
        }
        if(dot === 2){
            clicked_2 = true;
        }

        if(clicked_1 && clicked_2){
            document.getElementById("line0").style.visibility="visible";
        }
    }
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I should have came straight here.